# Rename all ".pdf" files to "_0.pdf"

Tags: command-line, rename, copy

I want to copy all files `*.pdf` to `*_0.pdf`

How can I do it?

Comment: Don't forget to inspect for collisions. The suggested scripts so far work but, if you run some of them with two files `abc.pdf` and `abc_0.pdf` then the renamed `abc.pdf` may overwrite `abc_0.pdf` before the latter gets renamed.

Answer (score 16):

A simple way would be to use the [mmv](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/mmv.1.html) command:

```
mmv '*.pdf' '#1_0.pdf'
```

---

You might need to install it first (available in the Universe repository):

```
sudo apt-get install mmv
```

Comment: To save you an `apt-cache show mmv`: _mmv is a program to move/copy/append/link multiple files according to a set of wildcard patterns. This multiple action is performed safely, i.e. without any unexpected deletion of files due to collisions of target names with existing filenames or with other target names._

Answer (score 10):

With `rename` (`prename`):

```
rename -n 's/\.pdf$/_0$&/' *.pdf
```

- `\.pdf$` matches `.pdf` at the end of the filename
- in the replacement, the match is prepended by `_0`: `_0$&`
- drop `-n` for actual action

---

With `bash` parameter expansion:

```
for f in *.pdf; do pre="${f%.pdf}"; echo mv -- "$f" "${pre}_0.pdf"; done
```

- `pre="${f%.pdf}"` saves the portion of the filename before `.pdf` as variable `pre`
- while `mv`-ing `_0.pdf` is appended to `$pre`: `${pre}_0.pdf`
- drop `echo` for actual action

---

**Example:**

```
% rename -n 's/\.pdf$/_0$&/' *.pdf
rename(egg.pdf, egg_0.pdf)
rename(spam.pdf, spam_0.pdf)

% for f in *.pdf; do pre="${f%.pdf}"; echo mv -- "$f" "${pre}_0.pdf"; done
mv -- egg.pdf egg_0.pdf
mv -- spam.pdf spam_0.pdf
```

Comment: with `rename.ul` it is even more simple ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind `rename.ul` which comes with `util-linux`, does not give enough flexibility to me while the `prename` (`perl` script) let me do all the `perl` capabilities. So `prename` is my way to deal with these stuffs.

Comment: `echo abc > abc.pdf; echo abc_0 > abc_0.pdf; for f in *.pdf; do pre="${f%.pdf}"; echo mv -- "$f" "${pre}_0.pdf"; done` (The `rename` version will skip instead of overwriting.)

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to rename or copy?

To rename, you can use emacs:

1. Open the parent directory as a dired buffer
2. Type `M-x wdired-change-to-wdired-mode`
3. Use `M-x query-replace` to replace '.pdf' with '_0.pdf'
4. Type `C-x C-s` to save the buffer

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to rename or copy the files?
For both, you can simply use a for loop and `mv` (move, also renames) or `cp` (copy):

```
for i in *.pdf; do mv "$i" "${i/%.pdf/_0.pdf}"; done
```

or rather

```
for i in *.pdf; do cp "$i" "${i/%.pdf/_0.pdf}"; done
```

The quotation marks are only needed if (one of) your files contains spaces.

Quick explanation: `${i/%.pdf/_0.pdf}` takes variable `i` and substitutes “.pdf” by “_0.pdf” if it is found at the end of the string (hence `%`). Read more about bash's amazing superpowers [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

Comment: Considering what _Denis de Bernardy_ wrote in his comment to the question: This solution will overwrite a file `abc_0.pdf` with the content of `abc.pdf`, but only after moving/copying `abc_0.pdf` to `abc_0_0.pdf` first, because `abc_0.pdf` comes before `abc.pdf` for the bash (with my localisation). When in doubt, just check the file order first with ` for i in *.pdf; do echo $i; done`.

Answer (score -1):

## Simple solution files on same directory

On **sh** shell, `rename` will help you:

`rename .pdf _0.pdf *.pdf`

Execute the comand on directory with the pdf files.

## Files inside directory recursive

If you have the files inside directories and want to find all of then and replace:

`find . -iname "*.pdf" | fgrep -v _0.pdf | xargs -n1 echo rename .pdf _0.pdf`

Comment: For the `rename` command, I got an error: `syntax error at (eval 1) line 1, near "."`

Comment: A bit stranger...

What shell you run the command?

Comment: `sh`, and `bash` for that matter

Comment: Though I can't see why that would make a difference, since it's `rename` reporting the syntax error, not the shell.

Comment: Oh, I think you just forgot the `rename` syntax. Try this instead: `rename 's/.pdf/_0.pdf/' *.pdf`

Comment: @wjandrea I think this refers to `rename` from `util-linux`, not `perl-rename`: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/rename.ul.1.html

Comment: Yeah, rename from util-linux :/

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't even know there was another rename program. You might want to make that clearer in your answer.

Comment: My bad.The truth is, i dont know about the other rename too :p